# Cron job is python script not executing automatically altough cron and Terminal was added to full disk access

Tags: terminal, applescript, python

I set up a cron job for writing every minute from a python script an entry into a log file which is created from the python script.
The python script is working fine if I execute it manually but it gets not executed automatically from running the cron job.

**Python script:**

```py
import logging
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(dir_path, 'test_log.log')

# Logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

def do_logging():
    logger.info("test")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_logging()
```

I added Terminal and cron to full disc access. The cron job was successfully created I am able to list the cron job with `crontab -l`. What could be the reason?

**Cron view:**

[image]

**Full disk access:[image]**

Comment: Is it using python2 or python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged my output of the cron job as following:

`* * * * * python /Users/maxhager/test/some.py > /Users/maxhager/test/backup.log 2>&1`

`> /Users/maxhager/test/backup.log 2>&1` is creating a file called backup.log and logs standard output and errors.

From this information I saw that my python was not found so I changed `python` to `python3` and it worked.

**Solution:**

`* * * * * python3 /Users/maxhager/test/some.py > /Users/maxhager/test/backup.log 2>&1`